# TortoiseGit - copy via sftp on pull

Tags: linux, windows, git, samba, tortoisegit

#### Intro:

I have 2 folders which are on the same GIT repository, one is on a **very** slow [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) network drive, and one locally. using GIT on samba is extremely slow, but the Samba is my server, which is actually vmplayer running ubuntu server on a windows machine.

#### My question is:

is it possible to automatically copy files from the local directory, after a pull has been done, to the other samba folder. I do this in Sublime text editor (via [addon](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)), but it copies only when I save a file. I want that functionality also on GIT. (i'm mainly using [TortoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/))

thanks.

Comment: um, samba on ubuntu server on vmware on windows. WHY? you do realize samba does "windows shares"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller - the server is on linux, and I must expose the files to windows as a network drive (samba) so i could interact with them with my sublime easily. But since it's so slow, I have a local copy which copies via SFTP to the ubuntu network drive, since i don't know of a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are git hooks. Have a look at

```
git help hooks
```

you can define what's automatically to be done after a pull. However, your system sounds insane and you should think about not doing that with the slow share. Also, I don't understand why an Ubuntu on a VMWare player would be really slow, unless you royally messed up configuration (not to mention I really don't understand why you wouldn't just let your windows do the shares, instead of letting a linux VM do that -- and I don't really like windows at all).

Comment: well, it's a very known thing that samba network drive on windows 7 are extremely slow.. if you google `samba windows slow` you'll see hundreds of people complaining and not even one solution which helps. My system is insane, but the server must be linux and I don't wish to work on a linux system locally, I like windows. What did you mean by "letting windows do the share" ?